# Is IIS7 Web Deploy Management Service accepting requests on 8172 or port 80 (or both?)

Tags: iis-7, msdeploy

Our support team have enabled the management service on IIS 7, windows server 2008. Remote connections are enabled and the connections port is 8172.

If I hit `https://localhost:8172/msdeploy.axd` I am prompted for a password.

If I run

```
C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V2>msdeploy -verb:getSystemInfo -source:webserver,computername=https://localhost:8172/MSDeploy.axd,username={username},password={password} -allowUntrusted -debug
```

I get a 401 error.

If I run

```
C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V2>msdeploy -verb:getSystemInfo -source:webserver,computername=localhost,username={username},password={password}
```

I get valid output XML.

So, how come the msdeploy.axd is running on ssl and yet I get a valid response over plain http?

UPDATE: Adding "authType=basic" corrects the 401 for msdeploy over 8172.

```
msdeploy -verb:getSystemInfo -source:webserver,computername=https://localhost:8172/MSDeploy.axd,username={user},password={password},authType=basic -allowUntrusted
```

Comment: did you get to the bottom of this, we're having the same problem. Port 80 and 8172 are kept open by MsDepSvc and I want to stop it hogging port 80.

Answer (score 0):

Are both machines on the same Active Directory domain?  If Basic is working then chances are the NTLM authentication isn't flowing through.  Ensure that you have enabled NTLM authentication as well (see [section 7](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd722796%28v=WS.10%29.aspx) on the web deployment handler setup)